# What's the difference between preferredStyle: .alert and preferredStyle: .actionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have been trying to implement a basic alert/dialog in our iOS app using UIAlertControl native UIKit's library.

Basically I was trying to add an UITextField as an input on this basic dialog.

During my experiments I realized I could not add text fields to UIAlertController when **`preferredStyle: .actionSheet`**.

It's only possible to add text fields (not text views - multiline) when **`preferredStyle: .alert`**.

***;TLDR;***

[Check out this image and see the difference between alert and actionsheet styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu0fB.jpg)

At first I didn't manage to understand the practical difference between `preferredStyle: .alert` and `preferredStyle: .actionSheet`. But I finally found these pieces of documentation (I confess wasn't able to find'em on Google - damn):

***Action Sheets*** - https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/action-sheets/

***Alerts*** - https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/alerts/

***Further reading*** -
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/getting_the_user_s_attention_with_alerts_and_action_sheets?language=objc

Thank you all for lighting it up!

Comment: It's related to two previous way to do it: `UIAlertView` & `UIActionSheet`. Search for them (in Google images for instance), you'll see. Now, it's combined in a single object `UIAlertController` and you decide the style.

Comment: Currently, it's this: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/action-sheets/ and https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/alerts/

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `UIAlertController`? Did you try running your code with both styles?

Comment: ...and you did not spot the difference on the screen between these two styles at all, right?

Comment: @Larme, thank you man! That's exactly what I was looking for! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two different styles.

Alert usually used when we need to show just a title and a message. Suppose after a network call, we can show the result of the network call. That time we use title "Success" or "Failed" and show just message, what actually has occurred.

Action sheet gives us alternative options. Suppose, log out is a case. "Do you want to log out?" definitely shows an alternative option, Do you really want to log out or not.

So we can easily say one thing, alert may contain multiple buttons, but action sheet will contain more than one button.

Destructive alerts type - "Do you want to delete contact" should be shown using action sheet.